# Query inside query on google spreadsheet

Tags: google-sheets

I need to query data from table and for where clause use result from another query

For example:

How to query for rows at this tab where date on column A is greater or equal date from another query on the tab shown at second image below. I want to write only the project number on the query or put a cell with the current project number and query for start and end dates where project is equal current project.

[image: Project Tasks]

[image: Project Dates]

The query will be something like this:

[image: Example Query]

Can you help me?

Answer (score 2):

Sure it's possible if you use appropriate syntax.

I suggest `query` + `filter` combination:

## Sheet1

```
Date    Col1    Col2
3/29/2017   a   a2
3/30/2017   b   b3
3/31/2017   c   c4
4/1/2017    d   d5
4/2/2017    e   e6
4/3/2017    f   f7
4/4/2017    g   g8
4/5/2017    h   h9
4/6/2017    i   i10
4/7/2017    j   j11
4/8/2017    k   k12
```

## Sheet2

```
Project   Date1         Date2
1         3/29/2017     4/1/2017
2         4/2/2017      4/5/2017
3         4/6/2017      4/8/2017
```

## Sheet3: Resulting formula

The formula is:

`=QUERY({Sheet1!A:C},"select * where Col1 >= date '"&TEXT(FILTER(Sheet2!B:B,Sheet2!A:A=1),"YYYY-MM-DD")&"' and Col1 <= date '"&TEXT(FILTER(Sheet2!C:C,Sheet2!A:A=1),"YYYY-MM-DD")&"'")`

The result:

```
Date    Col1    Col2
3/29/2017   a   a2
3/30/2017   b   b3
3/31/2017   c   c4
4/1/2017    d   d5
```

It's better to use filter once:

`=FILTER(Sheet2!B:C,Sheet2!A:A=1)`

to get dates for project #1 and then reference it's result.

Or even convert it to date format:

`=FILTER(text(Sheet2!B:C,"\dat\e 'YYYY-MM-DD'"),Sheet2!A:A=1)`

and get 2 strings:

```
date '2017-03-29'   date '2017-04-01'
```

---

I've also tried to use shorter query: `select * where Col1 between date '2017-03-29' and date '2017-04-01'` but `between` keyword is not supported.

Comment: Hello Max! Your query can help me! But, there is something I need yet. The date paramete passed in where must be obtained from another query. Something like this. `QUERY(AnotherSheet!A2:C; "SELECT B WHERE A = 1")` . A column is the project number and B and C columns is the start and end dates of the project. Your query helped me but this problem I not getting sucess to solve.

Comment: formula `=FILTER(text(Sheet2!B:C,"\dat\e 'YYYY-MM-DD'"),Sheet2!A:A=1)` has project nimber: `Sheet2!A:A=1`

Comment: I'm not getting success with your query. Do you think that something like this will work? `=QUERY({CSF!A2:J}; "SELECT A, B, C, D, E, F, G, H, I, J WHERE "' TO_DATE('"A"')'" >= '"&TEXT(FILTER(QUERY({Datas de Sprints!A2:C};"SELECT B WHERE A = 21");"dd/MM/yyyy"))&"' ")`

Comment: I used `{}` to convert data range into array, because I like using `Col1, Col2, Col3...` instead of `A, B, C`. To make this work you need to change `{CSF!A2:J}` into `CSF!A2:J` or change `A, B, C` into `Col1, Col2, Col3...`